# Docusaurus versionning

Tags: docusaurus

If I do not want to show this next in the dropdown nav menu, what should I do?

[image]

Checked the docusaurus documentation too, but could not understand.

Answer (score 0):

Docusaurus developers clearly explain how to do so in their official documentation [here](https://docusaurus.io/docs/versioning). However, if you prefer you can also watch [this video](https://youtu.be/Rc6mdSRaikE?t=896) in which I explain how to enable versioning in Docusaurus.